# How to trace .bat program output stream

Tags: c#, c++, console, trace

Problem description:
I have .bat executable which runs and performs certain tasks. If there occures an error it stops working and starts throwing error. The program source is missing.

Idea to go :
I'm making c# application, which gets the window of .bat using EnumWindows from user32.dll . Is it possible to trace somehow the output stream of .bat inside console window ? So i'll know when certain "string" appears inside output stream, and then fix the problem.

Or is there any other way to monitor .bat executable workflow, and know what it prints out ?

Thanks,

Joonas

Comment: Capture output: if you can run it in a process you can redirect is stdOut and especially its errOut. But fixing it???

Comment: How's this question related to java?

Comment: " .bat executable ... source is missing"? how you can run .bat if you are missing it?

Comment: Seems I dont have enoght knowladge on the topic. Example what i ment with "source". In C# you have source code and published app. Published app itself is not writtable - you need source to make changes in code but when u have published app you can run it. Its not like that in Java?